# Swift 3: Fast file path separation

Tags: swift, url, split, directory, filenames

I need to split parts of a file path for thousand of files. So I need a fast function. I wrote this by my own, but it seems to run very slow:

```
// find string in "str", split at the position, delivers left and right side

func revFindSplit_(str : String, searchString : String) -> (String, String) {
    let strr = String(str.characters.reversed())  // reverse main string
    let searchStringr = String(searchString.characters.reversed())    // reverse search string too

    if let strrindex = strr.range(of: searchStringr) {  // now we can search from back to front

        let rangeOfS2 = strr.characters.startIndex..<strrindex.lowerBound   // we got search result: part 1 (front)
        let rangeOfS1 = strrindex.lowerBound..<strr.characters.endIndex   // part 2 (back)
        let S2 = String(strr[rangeOfS2].characters.reversed()) //    put together and reverse again
        let S1 = String(strr[rangeOfS1].characters.reversed())

        // here we have to remove search string
        let S1M1 = String(S1.characters.prefix(S1.characters.count - searchString.characters.count))

        return (S1M1, S2)
    }
    else {
        return (str, "")   // without splitting
    }
}

// split path of filename into all 3 part: directory name, filename without extension, extension (without dot)
// in one call (faster than the 3 functions separatly)
func splitFilename_(str: String) -> (directory: String, filenameOnly: String, ext: String) {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: str)
    let path = url.path!

    // split path and filename
    let (directory, filenameExt) = revFindSplit_(str: path, searchString: "/")
    // split filename in filenameOnly and extension
    let (filenameOnly, ext) = revFindSplit_(str: filenameExt, searchString: ".")

    return (directory, filenameOnly, ext )
}
```

Is there any way to speed it up dramatically? (maybe using library functions)

Comment: I doubt you have a performance issue when using the solution by @vardian. But if that really isn't fast enough and you need a 'dramatic' speedup, grab the UTF8 from the string, `import Glibc` or `import Darwin` and use the C functions on that (like `basename`, `strstr` etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce your entire code:

```
func splitFilename(str: String) -> (directory: String, filenameOnly: String, ext: String) {
  let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: str)
  return (url.deletingLastPathComponent().path, url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent, url.pathExtension)
}
```

Comment: That's excellent. Exactly what I searched for. Because I'm starting now (with Swift 3.0), I want to do it right. :-) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting thousands of strings is not a big task by modern CPU standard. To put an Intel CPU in trouble, you would need millions. And are you sure this is the bottleneck of the your application?

> "Pre-mature optimization is the root of all evils" — Donald Knuth

And lastly, your code is epic! Have you try the path manipulation built-in to `NSString`?

```
func splitFileName(str: String) -> (directory: String, fileName: String, extension: String) {
    let path = str as NSString
    let directory = path.deletingLastPathComponent

    let fileNameWithExtension = path.lastPathComponent as NSString
    let fileNameWithoutExtension = fileNameWithExtension.deletingPathExtension
    let fileExtension = fileNameWithExtension.pathExtension

    return (directory, fileNameWithoutExtension, fileExtension)
}
```

Comment: Built-in path manipulation of `NSString`  is outdated in Swift. `URL` is preferable.

Comment: The methods are still there on `NSString` and `NSString` isn't going away anytime soon

Comment: Yes, but the state-of-the-art classes (actually structs) in **Swift(3)** are `String` and `URL`. There's a performance reason why Apple dropped the path manipulation methods in Swift `String` to encourage the developers to use the URL related API.